# How to block popup background in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make sure that parent view is unclickable when childview (aka popup) is active. But somehow I am able to select labels and buttons in parent view even when childview is on front. Can someone please help me on how can I disable parent view touch when child view is active. I referred this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE to create pop up view.

This is button code that actives popup view:

```
@IBAction func questionMark(_ sender: Any) {

let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionID") as! QuestionMarkViewController

self.addChild(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

}

Comment: are you talking about red one ?

Comment: if you looking at the video then you can see show button in the background which is clickable even when red popup is on. So all I need is to make the background of popUp unclickable when popUp is active

Answer (score 0):

You have to set isUserInteractionEnabled property of the UIViewControllers view to false if you have to disable any action to that ViewController. But you have to keep in mind this will include any child view's that is associated with it.

Since you are having the the popup view in the child view controller I would suggest you to create a view with clear color (or any blur effect view or any shades if you prefer) with frame as that of the parent view and add your popup to that view instead. By this way you can avoid any clickable actions to the parent view.